# Android Studio giving me an IOException when updating

Tags: android-studio, updates, ioexception

I am trying to update my Android Studio but it keeps giving me an error. It pops up with this screen
[image]

If I click proceed, this screen pops up
[image]

checking out the idea_updater.log file gives me this error

```
08/12 12:40:17 ERROR Patch.apply - apply failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot delete: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\runnerw.exe
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils.tryDelete(Utils.java:109)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils.access$000(Utils.java:12)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils$1.visitFile(Utils.java:72)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils$1.visitFile(Utils.java:69)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils.delete(Utils.java:69)
    at com.intellij.updater.BaseUpdateAction.replaceUpdated(BaseUpdateAction.java:115)
    at com.intellij.updater.UpdateAction.doApply(UpdateAction.java:66)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.apply(PatchAction.java:199)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.lambda$apply$3(Patch.java:399)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:471)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:390)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:64)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.install(Runner.java:366)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:138)
```

I have no idea what is going on, or what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this can happen if your computer is not fully up to date or is trying to install updates in the background. Updated my computer and it went through perfectly fine.